# error TS2538: Type 'CCCustomer' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: node.js, sonarqube

For below mentioned code facing error as error TS2538: Type 'CCCustomer' cannot be used as an index type.
with let index in ccCustomerList its working fine but in sonarqube received issue as Use "for...of" to iterate over this "Array". any alternative way available for this.

```
let data:Array<Customer>;

for (const index of CustomerList) {
    const Customer = CustomerList[index];
    const List: Array<string> = [];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, the `index` variable is not really an index of the array, but it's an object from the `Customerlist`, this is how `for of` works and that's why you get the error stating you can't use an object as an index.

So you don't need to get the customer from the `CustomerList` array since it's already there in your index variable.

Rename `index` to `Customer` and remove this line:

```
const Customer = CustomerList[index];
```

Replace all `CustomerList[index]` with `Customer` in your code.

### Example

```
for (const Customer of CustomerList) {
  const guidList: Array<string> = [];
  // Use Customer object
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

## Update

If you need to use an index use a regular loop or add `Array.entries()` to the current loop which returns the index and the value (just remove it if not needed).

### Example

```
for (const [index, value] of CustomerList.entries()) {
  const Customer = CustomerList[index];
  const guidList: Array<string> = [];
```